# Not able to see folder added in windows dockerfile

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile

Am pulling a windows servercore:lts2019 image as my base image, adding a folder to it and creating my own image called "mygitlabpath/windows-2019". The contents of the Dockerfile are as follows:

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
    ADD folder-z c:/windows/system32/config/systemprofile/folder-z
    SHELL ["powershell"] 
    RUN ls c:/windows/system32/config/systemprofile/folder-z ( at this step i see all contents of folder-z)
```

Now I use this image i created and try to access c:/windows/system32/config/systemprofile/folder-z but there is no such folder called folder-z :

```
image: mygitlabpath/windows-2019

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ls c:/windows/system32/config/systemprofile/ ( at this step i expect to see folder-z.. but i dont)
```

What is that am missing? Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are you running this in a GitLab CI pipeline?

Comment: @naraghi yes! I run this using gitlab ci pipeline; Should have mentioned it ... sorry!

Comment: What is the job  output?

Comment: ls c:/windows/system32/config/systemprofile/ shows "Directory: C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile with contents  .docker , .matplotlib, AppData                                                               and gitconfig ". folder-z is missing. Job ends with "job succeeded" after that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `COPY` instead of `ADD`. Works for me

Comment: @naranghi.. thanks for your reply. I tried COPY instead of ADD and still I do not see the folder-z...

Comment: Does folder-z exist on your docker host?

Comment: If you just want to add the folder to the container's file system without having it on the host, add `RUN mkdir -p c:/windows/system32/config/systemprofile/folder-z`